# execute code after Activity loads in Android

Tags: java, android, layout, oncreate

I'm trying my app format some images in the screen after the Activity loads. The problem is while inside `onCreate()`, `onResume()` methods my `ImageView` have width and height=0. How can I run some code after the views are resized?
I test `onPostResume()` but it dont work =(

Comment: I think your problem is in line 15, you should add a `;`. Or, less tongue in cheek: you might want to post the code that doesn't work (only a minimal example where it shows what doesn't work), and then tells us what you want, what you get, etc etc.

Comment: Dont think i need code for explain that a imageview with fill_parent height and width have height=0 and width=0 while le Activity loads and I want to execute code when the item take the real size..

Comment: I figured that much, that's why I added the comment. If you would've agreed in the first place, I guess you would have posted the code, right? right. It might be clear for you, but I have no quick insight in what's going on, so can't (and won't) help. Think about it: what view? is it set? how is it set? what should the size be? can we be sure about the size at the time you ask for it? Is the image set in code? When?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views in Android do not have fixed size/position like in Blackberry or iPhone; instead, they are layed out dynamically. Layout happens much later than `onCreate/onResume`, and theoretically can happen many times. Every view has methods `onMeasure` and `onLayout` which are responsible for that. Only after `onLayout` method returns you can tell the view's size and position. Before that the view's size is 0 and position is 0 (as you've noticed).

So it makes little sense trying to get ImageView's size in `onCreate/onResume` because `onLayout` hasn't yet been called at that point.

Instead, override `onLayout` like this and do your stuff there:

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        // at this point size and position are known
        int h = getHeight();
        int w = getWidth();
        doSomethingCool(h,w);
    }
}
```